# How to inherit stdin and stdout in python by using os.execv()

Tags: python, fork, stdout, stdin, execv

First, I wrote a c++ code as follows:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    while(scanf("%d %d",&a,&b) == 2)
        printf("%d\n",a+b);
    return 0;
}
```

I use `g++ -o a a.cpp` to complie it.

Afterwards, I wrote python code as follows:

```
import os,sys
sys.stdin = open("./data.in","r")
sys.stdout = open("./data.out","w")
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    cmd = ["./a","./a"]
    os.execv(cmd[0],cmd)
```

However, the `data.out` file contains nothing. That is to say, the child process did not inherit stdin and stdout from his parent process. But when I wrote a c++ code as follows:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstdio>
int main()
{
    freopen("data.in","r",stdin);a
    freopen("data.out","w",stdout);
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        char* cmd[]= {"./a","./a"};
        execv(cmd[0],cmd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got the right answer in the `data.out`, that is to say execv works in the c++ code.

So, what I should do to let execv also works in python? I really need this function to work, could anybody can tell me? thanks a lot!

`data.in` contains the following:

```
1 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your python code, you've opened *new IO streams* and set the `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` Python *names* to point to these. They will have their own file descriptors (most likely 3, and 4). However the standard file descriptors, `0`, and `1` will remain unchanged, and continue to point at their original locations. These are the descriptors inherited when you `exec` into stdin and stdout in your C++ program.

You need to make sure that the actual file descriptors are adjusted before execing.

```
os.dup2(sys.stdin.fileno(), 0)
os.dup2(sys.stdout.fileno(), 1)
```