# Python redirect stdin/stdout with execv

Tags: python, exec, posix, fork, multiprocess

I'm using python to `os.fork` a child progress, and use `os.execv` to execute another program in the child progress. How can I redirect I/O in the child program. I tried this but failed.

```
import sys, os

pid = os.fork()
if pid is 0:
    sys.stdin = open('./test.in')
    os.execv('/usr/bin/python', ['python', './test.py'])
```

While `test.py` is:

```
import sys

print(sys.stdin)
a = input()
print(a)
```

Comment: Look into the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : `subprocess` is good but not what I want, since I want to limit resource in the child process.

Comment: Looks like this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8500169/10601

Comment: `if pid is 0` is wrong. You must use `if pid == 0`. Your may happen to work in all versions of CPython (so far), but the language does not in any way guarantee that the 0 returned by `os.fork()` and the 0 against which you are comparing are the same 0 object. In future CPython versions or in other Python implementations like PyPy, they might very well not be the same 0.

Answer (score 3):

After `os.fork()` try this to redirect stdin and stderr:

```
import os

STDIN_FILENO = 0
STDOUT_FILENO = 1
STDERR_FILENO = 2

# redirect stdout            
new_stdout = os.open(stdout_file, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT|os.O_TRUNC)
os.dup2(new_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO)

# redirect stderr
new_stderr = os.open(stderr_file, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREAT|os.O_TRUNC)
os.dup2(new_stderr, STDERR_FILENO)
```

```